# Securely storing Client ID for SPA having OKTA Auth code flow with PKCE implementation

Tags: angular, security, okta, pkce

When implementing Auth code flow with PKCE for Angular app, do we need to securely store the **client ID** and **Issuer**? If so how can it be done? Because if I store it as environment variable and dynamically generate environment.ts files (containing the **client id** and **issuer**) these values can still be access in the browser as environment files in prod built can be accessed in the browser.

Are there any security threats in exposing the client ID and the Issuer?

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec itself: `https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.2` the client ID is not a secret by design, so there is no need to protect it.